# How do I put the last day of the month on its corresponding month of the year in MS excel?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, excel-2007

How do I put the last day of the month on its corresponding month of the year in Excel?
Because I need to do this from 2005 to 2025 in creating a Time Dimension Table. I tried to find a solution in Visual Studio but I didn't find any option to customize it.

```
COLUMN C                    COLUMN D

Friday, July 01, 2005       2005-07-31
Saturday, July 02, 2005     2005-07-31
Sunday, July 03, 2005       2005-07-31
Monday, July 04, 2005       2005-07-31
Tuesday, July 05, 2005      2005-07-31
.......
....
...
Wednesday, July 27, 2005    2005-07-31
Thursday, July 28, 2005     2005-07-31
Friday, July 29, 2005       2005-07-31
Saturday, July 30, 2005     2005-07-31
Sunday, July 31, 2005       2005-07-31
.....
...
..
Monday, August 01, 2005     2005-08-31
Tuesday, August 02, 2005    2005-08-31
Wednesday, August 03, 2005  2005-08-31
Thursday, August 04, 2005   2005-08-31
Friday, August 05, 2005     2005-08-31
```

and so forth all the way to year 2025

Thank you in advance!

Beau

Comment: Why is this tagged sql-server?

Comment: An alternative to Gordon or paulsm4 would be to use the EOMONTH function, as in =EOMONTH([COLUMN C], 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in Excel, you can do it with the following function:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1)+1, 1) - 1
```

Where `A1` contains the date in question.  The idea is to subtract one day from the first day of the next month.  Note:  Excel knows what to do with month 13.

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar, using datediff().  The key point: the last day of any month is first day of subsequent month - 1.

Comment: Thank you!! I saved a lot of time using this!

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction is not necessary. If the day is specified as 0, the last day of the previous month will be returned.

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0)
```